# Default icon for .exe file regardless of Windows version

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, exe, msdn

I show a bunch of exe files in a listview, and I want to show their default icon, but if the exe file has no icon resource, I would like to show the Windows default application icon regardless of the OS version. If I check the registries at:

```
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile\DefaultIcon]
```

the default value is "%1", which is the first icon in the exe file itself. But where is the default .exe icon for exe files with no icon?

Answer (score 0):

This is what XP does (this is actually a shortcut, but you get the point)

[image: Sample]

It's been awhile; but doesn't shell32 handle this?

Here's an older article from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460980/where-can-i-find-the-default-icons-used-for-folders-and-applications)

Comment: Yes, on XP they are located in shell32.dll, and in Win 7 they are located in imageres.dll. So it may vary from version to version.