# Getting The System's Folder Icon With SHGetFileInfo() - Getting Wrong Icon

Tags: winapi, directory, icons

I'm trying to retrieve the system's standard folder icon.

An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460980/where-can-i-find-the-default-icons-used-for-folders-and-applications) does indeed retrieve the icon in the hIcon member of the structure, but for me it gets the [system] drive icon, not the folder icon.

The iIcon member of the structure returns 80, so I also tried instead using SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX to get the relevant image list, then ImageList_GetIcon() using that iIcon member... but it *also* returned the drive icon. Interestingly, using SHGFI_OPENICON for the *open* folder image *also* gives 80 - making me think 80 is indeed the drive icon - so why is it giving me that one?

I'm on Windows 10. This is definitely NOT what my folder icon looks like - there's not been any weird redefinition.

Here's the original call (for the icon) I'm making:

```
        SHGetFileInfo(
            _T(""),
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,
            &sfi, sizeof sfi,
            SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
```

sfi.hIcon ends up with the drive icon.
sfi.iIcon ends up with 80 regardless of whether SHGFI_OPENICON is specified.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Pass a non-empty name (e.g. "foo"). As far as `SHGFI_OPENICON` goes, I don't think Windows actually uses/supports that much any more - at least Explorer no longer shows open icons.

Comment: That worked - please put it in as a full answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfow),

```
DWORD_PTR SHGetFileInfoW(
  [in]      LPCWSTR     pszPath,
            DWORD       dwFileAttributes,
  [in, out] SHFILEINFOW *psfi,
            UINT        cbFileInfo,
            UINT        uFlags
);
```

> If the *uFlags* parameter includes the **SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES** flag,
> this parameter does not have to be a valid file name. The function
> will proceed as if the file exists with the specified name and with
> the file attributes passed in the *dwFileAttributes* parameter. This
> allows you to obtain information about a file type by passing just the
> extension for *pszPath* and passing **FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL** in
> *dwFileAttributes*.

Comment: The problem here is "this parameter does not have to be a valid file name". That should say "this parameter must be _valid_ as a file name, but does not have to _exist_." My error was using an empty string for `pszPath`, thinking it didn't matter and not wanting random words in my code.

Comment: According to context, it could mean this parameter does not have to be the name of a valid file, which is also indicated by the following document.